# Telegram webhooks POST requests have empty payload

Tags: python, webhooks, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to register `webhooks` for my `Telegram bot` using the API call [`setWebhook`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook).

I got a public HTTPS url from [`ngrok`](https://ngrok.com/) for my local server which I passed to `setWebhook`.
Whenever a new message is being sent to my bot, I get a POST request to my local server as expected, however, request payload is empty.

Any idea?

Comment: how you get a POST request fom telegram? Can you paste a code here?

Answer (score 0):

Code please. I used curl on my web server to set the webhook.

Cheers

Edit.
I used this command on my wev server.
Optional ssl/tls cert.

curl -F "url=https://yourdomainname.com/mybot.php" -F "certificate=@/path/to/cert.pem" https://api.telegram.org/bot/setwebhook.php

Hope it helps man!!

Answer (score 0):

can try with

curl --location --request POST 'https://api.telegram.org/bot/setWebhook' 
--form 'url="https://88c23dd3cc13.ngrok.io/"'

update the ngrok url in the above command